# Runtime error 424: New version & Old Version

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I'm completely baffled...this macro looks at a `Range`, draws a number with `Rnd` then creates a `vlookup` to bring back a quote and author every time I open up my workbook (should one apply).

This error just began this evening, but only on today's versions. I am able to open up older versions and run the code just as expected.

Below is "Today's" latest copy and produces the Runtime error, with the break happening on the line defining the string `quote`:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim sht As Object
Dim RandNumb As Integer
Dim quote As String
Dim author As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Home")

  'Make "Home" Sheet visible and select
ws.Visible = True

  'Search for all sheets not named "Home" and hide them
For Each sht In Worksheets
    If sht.Name <> "Home" Then
    sht.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    End If
Next sht

  'Create random number, then vlookup based off number

RandNumb = Int((56 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
quote = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(RandNumb, Sheet3.Range("ba101:bc465"), 2, False)
author = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(RandNumb, Sheet3.Range("ba101:bc465"), 3, False)

If quote <> Empty Then
    MsgBox quote & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & " - " & author, vbOKOnly, "Quote of the day"
End If

End Sub
```

While the version from 2/6 works just fine:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim sht As Object
Dim RandNumb As Integer
Dim quote As String
Dim author As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Home")

  'Make "Home" Sheet visible and select
ws.Visible = True
ws.Select
Range("A1").Select

  'Search for all sheets not named "Home" and hide them
For Each sht In Worksheets
    If sht.Name <> "Home" Then
    sht.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    End If
Next sht

  'Create random number, then vlookup based off number

RandNumb = Int((56 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
quote = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(RandNumb, Sheet3.Range("ba101:bc465"), 2, False)
author = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(RandNumb, Sheet3.Range("ba101:bc465"), 3, False)

If quote <> Empty Then
    MsgBox quote & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & " - " & author, vbOKOnly, "Quote of the day"
End If

End Sub
```

These codes look no different to me. Even when I copy the version from 2/6 and put it in "Today's" I continue to receive the error. Help please.

Comment: The `Range` you are selecting in the second example (`"A1"`) doesn't seem to exist on that sheet.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't changed the codename of the Sheet3 sheet? Or declared a variable called `Application`?

Comment: Thanks @Rory, it was the `Sheet3`, in an attempt to organize, I changed it to `Sheet03`. This is one of the major issues I run into, making too many changes and not always remembering what I've done. Any suggestions?

Comment: You mean besides be more careful? ;) I'd suggest using more meaningful codenames before you start writing the code. If you do need to change them after that, use the Find/Replace dialog to update the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by @Rory; I had carelessly changed the name of the sheet but not in the code.